# Knockout computed triggering multiple times on a single action

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having an knockout issue with software that I work on but did not build. The page in question performs autosaves when almost any field is edited. The page displays multiple test questions, each of which has responses (answers) associated. The autosave is implemented with a dirty flag that compares the current state of the object to the initial state.

The symptoms I am seeing is that when visiting the page the first time and adding a new question causes 1 api call to be made for the 1 new question (which is correct). If I navigate to another page and come back to the same test (or a different one), all api calls are duplicated. If I repeat the same thing again, 3 calls (exactly the same) are made. My theory is that something in the VM/observable is not getting properly unset when leaving the page. I have debugged this a lot and I don't think there are multiple different actions triggering the save, but 1 action causing the triggering of the computed functions which triggers the autosave for every time that any test has been opened. Refreshing the browser causes this invisible counter to reset.

There are two computed functions

```
self.dirtyQuestions = ko.computed(function() {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.current.assessmentItems(), function(question) {
    return question.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
  });
}, self).extend({ throttle: 250 });

self.triggerDirtyQuestionSave = ko.computed(function() {
  if (!CONFIG.editing.autoSave) {
    return;
  }
  if (self.dirtyQuestions().length > 0) {
    self.saveQuestions(self.dirtyQuestions(), true);
  }
}, self);
```

that seem to depend solely on an observable array

```
  assessmentItems: ko.observableArray([]),
```

that is an object with many obsdervables associated with it. If any of these are modified or a new item is pushed, an autosave is triggered in the two computeds above. While debugging, I see these both being triggered multiple times after leaving and revisiting the pages, but all my breakpoints on modifications of the elements in the assessmentItems observable will only fire once.

My specific question is, how can I determine if something about the page/VM/observablearray is persisting after leaving the page that would cause an accumulation when leaving and returning to the page that might explain these duplicate triggers? The page is somewhat of a mess but also fairly complicated so I am trying to avoid having to re-write it or strip out all of the autosave features.

--update

Route table entry

```
        create: {
      enter: [
        checkForUnsavedChanges,
        function () {
          self.closeOverlay();
      }],
      to: function() {
        assessmentAuthoringVM = new AssessmentAuthoringVM(self);
      },
      exit: function() {
        if (assessmentAuthoringVM) {
          assessmentAuthoringVM.destroy();
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: If by leaving the page your browser actually navigates to a different page (as opposed to an SPA), then there's nothing on the client-side that gets retained (other than local storage - are you using that at all?). Nothing from the page will persist. Now, what *will* persist is anything that gets pushed to the server, and then retrieved back. Perhaps look at your data requests?

Comment: Have you checked to see if all event handlers are being unhooked?  Without seeing more code, it seems like you have lingering event handlers.  Check to see if the number of times the handler, or handlers, is being triggered is increasing.  If that number is increasing, that would be the problem.

Comment: @voithos: The application IS a SPA, sorry for not including that in the original description.

@ Eric: I did check the dependencyCount (ko.computedContext.getDependenciesCount() described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and really hoped that it would go up each time but it did not. Is there a lower-level event handler I can look at that wouldn't actually duplicate data? (ie, when new items are pushed into the observablearray, there are never 2 pushed in when the double trigger occurs). 

Thanks for the replies guys.

Comment: @LukeRice: It's difficult for us to determine the problem without having more information. Is your site public-facing? If not, is there other parts of the app that you think may be relevant? Also, here's a random guess: does the page rerun the viewmodel initialization functions every time you navigate to it? If so, then it may be recreating and binding multiple instances of the viewmodel to the DOM, which would explain the compounding API calls.

Comment: @voithos that sounds like what is probably happening, I will paste an update in the original post with the route-table entry for what (I think) contains the issue. So it is possible that there are two observablearrays bound to the same DOM elements? Is there a way to debug this in realtime that you know of? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @LukeRice: Unfortunately, the route table code doesn't say much, other than that on exit it tries to destroy the bindings. A [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/McHEY/) shows that Knockout (I believe versions 2.3 and above) will throw an error if you try to rebind twice. So, at this point, I'd say just try putting some `console.log`s around the code to see what's happening to the viewmodel as time goes on.

Comment: If it's a SPA, what is the routing mechanism?  Does it tear down the DOM for the pages that are not currently visible?  I've seen issues before where the page (and its subscribers) remain active even though it looks like you left the page.

Comment: I dropped KO 2.3.0 in to test the duplicate bindings theory and it turns out that that is not it. The way the routing works is very gnarly, the entire DOM is created up front and is always present, and the observablearray that is triggering the computeds that result in the duplicate requests is part of a global root VM that is never re-created. There is only 1 ko.applyBindings, and it is done as soon as the page loads. I was able to drop in ko 2.3.0 and there were no duplicate bindings unless I manually created them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function that runs when the "page" is closed, you should add calls to "dispose" the computed observables:

```
destroy: function () {
    self.triggerDirtyQuestionSave.dispose();
    self.dirtyQuestions.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I will give that a try, I had the same idea on the drive home yesterday but I haven't tried it yet. Thanks

Comment: That was it amazingly. I had tried disposing them (manually) before, but I realized that there is a compounding bug whereby if I click something in the page before navigating away, the destroy method is not actually called so. I've encountered 2 or 3 compounding bugs/ineffective hacky fixes along the way that made this a total pain to diagnose. Thanks dude.